# Is there a way to designate X in y = (k1 + k2 × x) mod (s)?

Tags: c#, math, modulo

I'm writting program in c# that needs to find X where greatest common divisor of k2 and s is 1, x is smaller than s and k1,k2,y,s are constants. Right now, I'm doing it by tring every value of X and checking if they are right, but that is very time consumig when I have like 40000+ values in it. Or if it's easier for you, you can try to designate X from y=x mod(s).

There is code I'm using right now to solve it:

```
if (GCD(k2, k) == 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            {
                n1 = 0;
                n = 0;
                while(n < 1)
                {
                    if(i == (k1 + k2 * n1) % k){
                        s1[n1] = s[i];
                        n++;
                    }
                    n1++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

P.S. If something is unclear, then let me know, it's kind of hard for me to explain all this :P

Comment: You want to find the biggest number both numbers can devide? for example 4 for 12 and 20?

Comment: Can you give a numeric example with solutions that you know? What are typical values of y, k1, k2, s and x?

Comment: Hint: Do you know what a *multiplicative inverse* is?

Comment: Example: 17395=(100+43*X)mod(633424), here X=17395, 24302=(100+43*X)mod(40000), here X=5214

Unfortunately I do not know what multiplicative inverse, can it help me to solve my problem?:P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through a sample problem:

```
Solve for X:
17395 = (100 + 43 * X ) % 633424
```

Start by eliminating the addition:

```
17395 - 100 = (43 * X) % 633424
17294 = (43 * X) % 633424
```

Now, suppose there exists a number Y such that

```
1 = ( Y * 43 ) % 633424
```

(Aside: How do we know that Y exists? It exists iff 43 and 633424 are coprime, which they are. This is a particular case of Bézout's identity.)

Y is the *multiplicative inverse of 43 with respect to 633424*.

How does this help?  We can multiply both sides by 17294:

```
17294 = ( Y * 43 * 17294 ) % 633424
```

And now we can read off our solution: X is `Y * 17294`.

So the problem reduces to computing the multiplicative inverse.  Can you see how to find a number Y such that `1 = ( Y * 43 ) % 633424` ? If you can find that number then you can find X.

You can use Euclid's Algorithm to quickly find the multiplicative inverse. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse or my page on the subject https://ericlippert.com/2013/11/12/math-from-scratch-part-thirteen-multiplicative-inverses/